# How to understand ‘to say’ in ‘I find it difficult to know what to say.’?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

> I find it difficult to know what **to say**.

Why not say:

> I find it difficult to know what **was said**.

I can not understand **to say** in the first sentence.

Comment: In a conversation the first means I understand it but don't know how to reply; the second means I don't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I find it difficult to know what to say" means "I do not know **what I should say** (in the present or future)"

> Why not say:* I find it difficult to know what was said.*?

Because this means "I do not know what one or more other people said (in the past)"

When discussing knowledge, or its lack, using interrogative words (what, where, when, who, etc) as relative pronouns, we use the infinitive form of a verb:

> I don't know what **to say**.
>
> Do you know where **to go**?
>
> He knows what **to do**.
>
> We don't know who **to ask**.
>
> You don't know when **to stop**.